# Serach List names in a dataframe column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am trying to match my list of server with the pandas dataframe in the column `Server Name`  if the name in the list matches in the `Server Name` then print the entire row.

there are chances names is the `my_List` do not match entirely like one of the server name in my_List is `tick1001.example.us.com` while in `Server Name`.

**This this my kind of list**

```
my_List = ['tick1001.example.us.com\n', 'tick2001.example.us.com\n', 'tick1003.example.us.com\n']
```

**Below is the Data Sample.**

```
 Server         Server Name             Model                   Processor                          Proc. Count  Memory  Serial Number   iLO iLO FW  Firmware    Appliance Name  VIC
enc2021, bay 1  tick2041.example.us.com ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M272300GJ  1. 10.127.3.31  2.53 May 03 2017    I36 v2.40 (02/17/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2013, bay 1  tpc2111.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M2708026H  1. 10.127.1.198 2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
enc1018, bay 1  tpc1173.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101PR  1. 10.127.2.143 2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC1002, bay 1  tpc1012.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M26250531  1. 10.127.0.109 2.40 Dec 02 2015    I36 v2.00 (12/28/2015)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC1005, bay 1  tick1003.example.us.com ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262505VB  1. 10.127.0.70  2.62 Jan 09 2019    I36 v2.72 (03/25/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2003, bay 1  tpc2023.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262602L6  1. 10.127.0.234 2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
enc2015, bay 1  tpc2141.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101ML  1. 10.127.2.173 2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
enc2016, bay 1  tpc2156.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101PJ  1. 10.127.2.188 2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
enc1013, bay 1  tpc1098.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101N0  1. 10.127.2.68  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
enc2019, bay 1  tpc2201.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101NQ  1. 10.127.2.233 2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2005, bay 1  tick2001    ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M26360507  1. 10.127.0.78  2.62 Jan 09 2019    I36 v2.72 (03/25/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2006, bay 1  tick1001    ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M263604ZZ  1. 10.127.0.58  2.40 Dec 02 2015    I36 v2.20 (05/05/2016)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2009, bay 1  tpc2060.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz   2   393216  2M263800Y4  1. 10.127.1.68  2.70 May 07 2019    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
enc1025, bay 1  tpc1250.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v3 @ 3.20GHz   2   393216  2M26100687  1. 10.127.3.231 2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2008, bay 1  tpc2045.example.us.com  ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M264800VR  1. 10.127.1.53  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
```

**Below is my code tried:**

```
import pandas as pd
my_List = open("vic_hosts").readlines()

df = pd.read_csv('report.csv')
df = [df['Server Name'].isin(my_List)]
print(df)
```

**Expected:**

```
Server          Server Name             Model                   Processor                          Proc. Count  Memory  Serial Number   iLO iLO FW  Firmware    Appliance Name  VIC
ENC1005, bay 1  tick1003.example.us.com ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262505VB  1. 10.127.0.70  2.62 Jan 09 2019    I36 v2.72 (03/25/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2005, bay 1  tick2001    ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M26360507  1. 10.127.0.78  2.62 Jan 09 2019    I36 v2.72 (03/25/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
ENC2006, bay 1  tick1001    ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M263604ZZ  1. 10.127.0.58  2.40 Dec 02 2015    I36 v2.20 (05/05/2016)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

Use `read().splitlines()` as every line comes with its end of line characters (\n\r) as in your example; this way the characters are removed.

```
my_List = open('vic_hosts').read().splitlines()

df = pd.read_csv('report.csv')
df = df[df['Server Name'].isin(my_List)]
print(df)
```

this should be working.